# How to get JSONResult in MVC and display using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

The below call successfully call an action in MVC and returning JsonResult which is a list of data. However below code the alert('aa') does not get called, can please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var url = "IndexJson";
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            alert('aa');
            var optionAdded = [];
            var i = 0;
            var length = data.length;
            for (var a = 0; a < length; a += 1) {
                optionAdded[i++] = data[a].OrderNo;
                optionAdded[i++] = ',';
            }
            $("#Company").append(optionAdded.join(''));
        });
    }
    test();
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know that the call is successful? Firebug?

Comment: I set breakpoint in the IndexJson action and it get called, so I know the controller is passing back the data, however the function(data) does not trigger.

Comment: Try using $.ajax and handle the error and complete callbacks to see if they are triggered instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue today.
After some debugging of jQuery core library it turned out that jQuery fails to parse response from json to javascript object because it's already javascript object.

In my case replacing $.getJSON with just $.get resolved the issue.